# ページ内に埋め込んだ外部サイトの（DOM操作などが行われた）現時点でのHTMLを取得したい

Tags: javascript, php, html

javascriptで要素が追加されたり、削除されたり変化する外部サイト(別ドメイン)を
自社Webサイト内で表示し、特定のタイミング(ボタンを押したときなど)でその外部サイトのソースコードを取得する仕組みを検討しています。

外部サイト(提携先)はクロスドメインの設定がされており、自社の管理外にあるため修正ができない状態にあるので、postMessageなどのクロスドメイン回避の方法は使用できず、phpにてURLを参照したソースコードの取得についても、javascriptでhtml内の要素が変化してしまうため、こちらの指定したタイミングでのソースコードが取得できません。

javascript、phpに限った話ではないので 他言語、開発環境でも構いませんので、ブラウザにて自社サイト内で外部サイトを表示し、希望のタイミングでその時のソースコードを取得するなどは機能的に不可能なのでしょうか。

もし上記がクリアできる方法をご存知の方がいらっしゃいましたらご教授お願いできればと思います。

※ほか質問サイトにも投稿させていただいておりますが、急ぎの情報収集、また情報収集が難航しているため、誠に失礼ながら似た質問をこちらにも掲載させていただいていますことを、ご容赦お願いいたします。

Comment: ご回答ありがとうございます。追加でのご質問でご質問で申し訳ありません。
おっしゃっている方法はphpでurlからソースコードを取得して手前どものサーバで表示する、というような以下リンクのような手法でしょうか？
http://www.webopixel.net/javascript/308.html

Comment: そうですね、そんな感じをイメージしてます。

Comment: 現在のＤＯＭツリーをソースで欲しいのにＵＲＬでソースを要求してもダメですね。勘違いしていましたすみません(unaristさんの編集で気が付きました）。

Comment: ところでIFRAMEを使って埋め込んでいるということでしょうか？

Comment: 引き続きご返答ありがとうございます。当初はiframeを埋め込んでそのソースコードをと考えていたのですがクロスドメイン規約があり、外部サイトのコード、及びサーバが変更できないと回避できないということでiframeのほうは手詰まりしてしまい、phpを使った手法ではできないかと模索していたところではあります。

Comment: IFRAMEにしてしまうとクロスドメイン制約で読み出しのみであっても不可ですから、ムリですね。結局具体的に「埋め込んだ外部サイト」とはどのように埋め込まれているのでしょうか？

Comment: 例えば、外部サイトのソースを取り込んでおいて自ドメインのアドレスでIFRAMEのアドレスにするのは可能ですか？

Comment: 返事が遅れてしまって申し訳ありません。外部に「外部に埋め込んだ外部サイト」についてはiframeを使う他にphpなどで取得したソースを埋め込んだりなどもしましたがダメでした。"外部サイトのソースを取り込んでおいて自ドメインのアドレスでIFRAMEのアドレス"について外部サイトのソースを自サイトで表示して、それをiframeで表示するということでしょうか。

Comment: まあ、そういうことです。ソースについては、参照アドレスなんかも変換する必要があるかもしれません。そういう使い方が提携先との契約でNGだとダメですが。「他にphpなどで取‌​得したソースを埋め込んだりなどもしました‌​がダメでした。」具体的にどうやっているのか、どうだめだったのかの説明がないと具体的な回答は付きにくいと思います。

Comment: 例えば、PHPでHTML文書を作成している表示しているのなら、そのページの中のjavascriptはDOMにアクセスできるはずなのに「ダメ」とはどういうことか？ということですね。長大なソースとか外部に見せられないものを貼り付けられても困るので、模式的な最小限の試してみることが可能なサンプルで具体的に説明して欲しいです。

Comment: 「ダメ」である原因はその外部サイトの中で、外部サイトドメイン内を参照しているリンクや画像などが多数あり正しく表示されない、またリンクのボタンを押すと外部サイトに飛んでしまうためです。
擬似的な可能なサンプルについて、作成できればと思うのですが、少々複雑で実際の環境になるべく似せるのに少々難航しております。。。
文章のみのご説明になってしまい申し訳ございません。

Comment: なんか、外部サイトのDOMを取得してeventをフックしたいって
偽装してsubmitした時にIDとパスワード抜きたい
にしか読み取れないです